# SUPER/Administrative privileges: no users of my database have them [Error Code 1227: Access denied]

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

My working group has a (very) small database that lives on the Google Cloud SQL platform. We are a group of ~8 ecologists new to SQL database management, and new to the Google Cloud platform. We are working with MySQL Workbench.

We have been creating views in SQL to summarize & aggregate our raw tables. Sometimes (often) MySQL yells at us and says:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause...

We can futz with our views, adding all the group by variables in til the cows come home, but really it would be nice to just re-set that global "group by" variable, ala

> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT
>   REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

But at this point, MySQL gets even grouchier and says

> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER
>   privilege(s) for this operation

So then I thought, no problem! I created this database, can't I just add myself as an administrator?

> GRANT SUPER ON ourdb.* TO myusername@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY
>   'password';

Oh, no, not so simple it turns out! ACCESS DENIED!

I tried logging in as root as well. ACCESS DENIED FOR ROOT!

AH! I think I have done something very bad, because NO ONE on our database has DBA privileges. I see this when I navigate in MySQL workbench to "Users and Privileges."

What have I done, and can I un-do it??

A million thanks to the SQL-ers of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries my friend!

You probably (as far as I can tell) have done nothing bad!

According to Google’s [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user), the root user has all privileges but SUPER and FILE. It’s a characteristic of the Google Cloud SQL.

But rest assured! You have three other ways of easily changing that global "group by" variable that has been slowing your progress. There’s a neat explanation on this [Configuring database flags how-to guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#determining_what_database_flags_have_been_set_for_an_instance).

I hope this helps you!

---

Comment: Thank you for your help, and for pointing me towards this documentation. I logged on to my Google Cloud Platform console, navigated to my instance, then clicked on "Edit." From there I "added a database flag." From the drop-down menu I selected the flag "sql_mode" and then clicked on all the strings that were listed in the default for my version of MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) -- all *except* the "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" string. Waited three seconds for my instance to update, and voila! I was on to dealing with other newbie problems :) Yay database community ! TY!